# Searching by NSDate in Coredata not working - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am searching for a record in coredata by a specific NSDate but it's returning no results.  It does not throw any error too..

When I loop through all the records I can output to the console the date.

Here is the predicate.. **created** is NSDate

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "created == %@", created)
```

..After digging around some more, the issue appears to be when I am handling the JSON of the timestamp:

```
var createdJSON:String = subJson["created"].string!
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")

var dateConverted:NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(createdJSON)!
```

The time was stored in the MySQL database under eastern timezone, and maybe that's my mistake?  Even though I can convert that JSON response to appear to be the same value, maybe it has to be UTC from the beginning?

-edit-

Converting to UTC does not help.

Comment: Keep in mind that an `NSDate` is accurate to the millisecond. It's unlikely you have any dates equal to `created` down to the millisecond value.

Comment: Ah, that might be it... it was stored from the MySQL format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" let me see what adding ms will do

Comment: Setting the milliseconds to the nsdate then using that does not work...

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have better luck if you search for a date range e.g.

```
let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "created >= %@ AND created <= %@", startDate, endDate)
```

where startDate and endDate are NSDates that you expect your results to fall between.

Comment: I don't understand why setting a +/- range of 1 second works, but setting the range of 1ms does not yield any results.  The smallest part of the timestamp I am storing are seconds.